# Showing that $|T(x)-T(y)| \geq c|x-y|$ for $x,y$ with $|x-y| \geq \alpha$ implies $|T(x)-T(y)| \geq c|x-y|$ for all $x,y$ when $T$ is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be a linear map and $B=B(x,r)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $r>0$. Suppose $T$ satisfies the following:

> There is an $\alpha >0$ and $c>0$ such that for all $x,y \in B$ with $|x-y| \geq \alpha$ , we have $|T(x)-T(y)| \geq c |x-y|$.

I have been hinted that this should imply actually that $|T(x)-T(y)| \geq c|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in B$. In other words, to show that $|T(x)-T(y)| \geq c|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in B$, is it enough to show the inequality for pairs of points which are far apart?

I think it should follow from homogeneity but I am failing to see how. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: There may be no elements $x,y$ in $B$ that satisfy the condition $|x-y|\geq \alpha$ because for any $x,y\in B$, $|x-y|\leq 2r$.

Comment: Fair enough, we can also assume that $\alpha$ is much smaller than $r$.